# Different ng-switch animations

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a simple slide animation on ng-switch.I would like to have a different one when the animation is finished the first time.How can i do that.Here is the class im using:

```css
.ngSwitchAnimation {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.ngSwitchAnimation.ng-enter,
.ngSwitchAnimation.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition : 0.5s linear all;
    -moz-transition    : 0.5s linear all;
    -ms-transition     : 0.5s linear all;
    -o-transition      : 0.5s linear all;
    transition         : 0.5s linear all;
}

.ngSwitchAnimation.ng-enter {
    left: -100%;
}
.ngSwitchAnimation.ng-enter-active {
    left: 0;
}
.ngSwitchAnimation.ng-leave {
    left: 0;
}
.ngSwitchAnimation.ng-leave-active {
    left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I want to do the opposite of this animation the second time

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example below, where opacity is 0 put one state, where 1 oposite.

```
.animate-if {
  background:white;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
}

.animate-if.ng-enter, .animate-if.ng-leave {
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
}

.animate-if.ng-enter,
.animate-if.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}

.animate-if.ng-leave,
.animate-if.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```